# Running 'ipython notebook' gets [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

Tags: python, sockets, jupyter-notebook

I'm on Mac OS 10.10.4.
When I run `ipython notebook` from command line, it gives me an error `Cannot bind to localhost, using 127.0.0.1 as default ip [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address`:

```
Yans-MacBook-Pro:/ yanyang$ ipython notebook
[W 01:32:12.908 NotebookApp] Cannot bind to localhost, using 127.0.0.1 as default ip
    [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
[I 01:32:12.912 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /
[I 01:32:12.913 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 01:32:12.913 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
[I 01:32:12.913 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

It will cause more error later. How can I fix it?

```
localhost:~ yanyang$ lsof | grep 8888
Google      358 yanyang  txt      REG                1,4   16621568 26888859 /Users/yanyang/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Profile 5/Cache/data_4
Google      358 yanyang   90u     REG                1,4   16621568 26888859 /Users/yanyang/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Profile 5/Cache/data_4
Google      358 yanyang  205u     REG                1,4       3072 35352297 /Users/yanyang/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 5/Local Storage/http_127.0.0.1_8888.localstorage
```

Content of the file in the last line of the above block:

```
?????z!11?tableItemTableItemTableCREATE TABLE ItemTable (key TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE, value BLOB NOT NULL ON CONFLICT FAIL)[!}1indexsqlite_aut?S???widgets:http://127.0.0.1:8888/notebooks/Downloads/PhillyCrime.ipynb{}?*?Qwidgets:http://127.0.0.1:8888/notebooks/Users/yanyang/Downloads/PhillyCrime.ipynb{}
??X?
    ?widgets:http://127.0.0.1:8888/notebooks/Downloads/PhillyCrime.ipynb?&?Q    widgets:http://127.0.0.1:8888/notebooks/Users/yanyang/Downloads/PhillyCrime.ipynb
```

Comment: Something else running on port 8888? Check using a `lsof | grep 8888`

Comment: @Petesh I updated the question and put the result of `lsof | grep 8888` at the bottom.

Comment: apologies, that should have been `lsof -nP | grep 8888` to determine what's already bound to port 8888; but the file suggests that there's something running on port `8888` already - you should change the notebook port to something else - edit the notebook's `ipython_config.py` to use a different port

Comment: @Petesh I find two `ipython_config.py` files in my computer but didn't find the place to modify the port. Also I got the content of `http_127.0.0.1_8888.localstorage` and added it to the bottom of the question. It seems to be related with the ipynb file I'm going to check itself.

Comment: Should I delete `http_127.0.0.1_8888.localstorage`?

Comment: I can't give you any more direction here - it sounds like ?chrome? is running the notebook already. Maybe quitting chrome would help? At this point all we can tell is that there is **something else** bound to port `8888`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102258/discussion-between-yan-yang-and-petesh).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks to @Petesh, I can use ipython notebook temperately now, using the command below:

```
ipython notebook --ip=127.0.0.1
```

And for further solution, I found that in my Mac's "/etc/hosts", 127.0.0.1 is not set to localhost. That's the final solution.

Comment: Hey thanks for this man! I would've been searching for a while if I did not come across your solution.

Comment: Why on earth I had extra entries for `localhost` in `/etc/hosts` I have no idea, but indeed, once I got rid of any that were not `127.0.0.1` Jupyter fired right up.

Comment: Thank you @Petesh for this answer.  Worked like a charm.